# Transliteration and text help for the nisim b'chol yom

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, translation, transliteration

My son is becoming a bar mitzvah, and he specified that he wanted to use a translation of the nisim b'chol yom (for daily miracles) prayer not from the siddur, but from a hand out in Hebrew school. I am fine with this, and am trying to create a word document so that it can go to the printer. However it is taking me an hour to just write out the Brauch atah adoni eloheimu melech haolam in Hebrew. I cannot find the version he wants on line.

But I was curious and used google translate and the meaning of the words that I got back was not the same as the text before me. So I am asking, is the translation of the following correct?

baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech haolam
asher natan lasechvi vinah l’havchinb bein 
uvein Laila.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who separates day and night.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
pokei-ach ivirim.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who opens our eyes.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
matir asurim.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who provides for all my needs.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
Hameichin mitzadei gaver.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who guides our journeys.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
Malbish arumim.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who provides clothing and shelter.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
hanotein laya-eif ko-ach.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who gives us strength when we are tired.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
hamaavir sheinah mei-einai, utnumah mei-afapai.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who removes sleep from the eyes, slumber from the eyelids.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
she-asani b’tzelem Elohim.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who made me in the image of God.

Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech ha’olam,
she-asani Yisrael.
Praise to You, Adonai our God, Ruler of the world, who encourages me to explore my Jewish heritage.

Does this transliteration mean what was written in english?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lisa, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! I edited your post thinking it was two unrelated questions, but then a little googling taught me that it's really all about the same set of blessings. Sorry about my confusion.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers, and especially the links. I greatly appreciate the time you took to look into this on my behalf.

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't heard of the "Nisim B'chol Yom" prayer you refer to, but I did some googling and discovered that this is another name for what I'm used to calling the "Birchot Hashachar" - "Morning Blessings."

You can find an online copy of these blessings in Hebrew and English at Sefaria.org [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Morning_Blessings?lang=bi). The Hebrew is from the "[Daat](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/tohen3.htm)" online repository at Herzog College, and the English is a "community translation" written by Sefaria's users.

The translation at Sefaria hews pretty close to the plain meaning of the Hebrew words. If you compare it to the version from your handout, you'll see that the handout's translation is a little more interpretive. For example, "*Hameichin mitzadei gaver*" is translated plainly in Sefaria as "who prepares the steps of man" and more freely in the handout as "who guides our journeys." In addition, if you've copied the entire handout into your question, then it looks like it does not include all of the blessings in the traditional sequence.

Mazal tov! I hope your son's bar mitzva celebration launches him into a long life of Jewish adulthood that features appreciation of and aspiration to be deserving of all of these blessings.

Comment: I would think "hameichin" in context would more literally be translated as "who steadies".

Comment: @Loewian מכין is rooted in הכנה, which means "preparation." Perhaps you are confusing it with מכלכל, which means "sustain," and can, in a sense, be defined as "steadies."